# Can't build graph by neo4j in three relationships

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have 3 files for building a graph on neo4j.

member.csv

```
memberID
1
2
3
```

member_visit

```
visitID memberID    visitDateTime
1       1           1/1/2020
2       1           1/5/2020
3       2           4/2/2020
4       3           1/5/2020
5       3           3/7/2020
```

member_product1

```
p1ID    memberID    visitDateTime   productName_1
1       1           1/1/2020        Coco
2       1           1/5/2020        Water
3       2           4/2/2020        Snack
4       3           1/5/2020        iPhone
5       3           3/7/2020        iPad
```

I use neo4j browser to create nodes and relationships

```
////////////////// LOAD DATA //////////////////
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member.csv' AS row
MERGE (member: Member {memberID: row.memberID})
RETURN member limit 20;


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member_visit.csv' AS row
MERGE (visit:Visit {visitID: toInteger(row.visitID)})
  ON CREATE SET visit.memberID = toInteger(row.memberID), visit.visitDateTime = row.visitDateTime
RETURN visit limit 20;


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member_product1.csv' AS row
MERGE (pro1:Pro1 {p1ID: toInteger(row.p1ID)})
  ON CREATE SET pro1.memberID = toInteger(row.memberID), pro1.visitDateTime = row.visitDateTime, pro1.productName_1 = row.productName_1
RETURN pro1 limit 20;



////////////////// MATCH DATA //////////////////

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member_visit.csv' AS row
MATCH (visit:Visit {visitID: toInteger(row.visitID)})
MATCH (member:Member {memberID: row.memberID})
MERGE (visit)-[pv:visited]->(member)
  ON CREATE SET pv.memberID = toInteger(row.memberID), pv.visitDateTime = row.visitDateTime


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member_product1.csv' AS row
MATCH (pro1:Pro1 {p1ID: toInteger(row.p1ID)})
MATCH (visit:Visit {visitID: toInteger(row.visitID)})
MERGE (pro1)-[vpm:bought]->(visit)
  ON CREATE SET vpm.memberID = toInteger(row.memberID), vpm.visitDateTime = row.visitDateTime, vpm.productName_1 = productName_1
```

In above code, it can build [member] to [visit] with code (visit)-[pv:visited]->(member)

[image]

**But I can't build [visit] to [productName_1] with code (pro1)-[vpm:bought]->(visit)**

***I expect this graph***

[image]

Could you please help me to check? What's wrong? Why it can't work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the 3rd file (`member_product1.csv`) subsumes the other two, and is the only one you need.

And it does not seem like you really need the `Visit` nodes at all, since you can put the `visitDateTime` in a direct relationship between the `Member` and `Pro1` nodes.

Finally, there is no need to redundantly store in a node the IDs of the nodes it has relationships with.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///member_product1.csv' AS row
MERGE (m:Member {id: TOINTEGER(row.memberID)})
MERGE (p:Pro1 {id: TOINTEGER(row.p1ID)})
ON CREATE SET p.productName_1 = row.productName_1
MERGE path=(m)-[:BOUGHT {visitDateTime: row.visitDateTime}]->(p)
RETURN path
LIMIT 20;
```

The above query will generate paths like this:

```
(:Member {id: 123})-[:BOUGHT {visitDateTime: '1234567890'}]->(:Pro1 {id: 234})
```

or, visually:

[image: 1]